# Type definition for an object with generic keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to find a type definition for something as follows:

```
const x: Keys<"A"|"B"> = {
 "A": number, // type of value never changes and doesn't need to be generic
 "B": number
};
```

Ideally, objects of this `Keys<T>` type would require having a key for every type in `T`, and couldn't have a key that's not under `T`. The closest I've gotten is `type Keys<T> = { [key in T]: number }`, but then when used as follows:

```
const obj: Keys<"x"|"y"> = { "x": 1, "y": 2 };
obj["x"] // TS compiler fails with below message
```

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"x"' can't be used to index type '{ x: number; } | { y: number; }'.
Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ a: number; } | { b: number; }'.ts(7053)

I've also tried several variants of passing the generic type parameter as an array, so like `Keys<["key1", "key2"]>`, to less success than what I have above.

Comment: `const obj: Record<"x" | "y", number> = {`

Comment: `type Keys<T> = { [key in T]: number }` is very close to being right and your error [is not reproducible](https://tsplay.dev/mAVeXW). Looks like the error is caused by some union distribution but you haven't shown it to us. Please endeavor to produce a [mre] that demonstrates your problem so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick, an object which receives the keys and has the value typed as numbers:

```
type Keys<K extends string> = Record<K, number>;

const obj: Keys<"x"|"y"> = { "x": 1, "y": 2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simplified my question from the real example I'm working with, and this simplification turned out to be non-trivial.

`type Keys<K extends string> = Record<K, number>;` or `type Keys<T> = { [key in T]: number }` fit the criteria of this post.